# Get string between two strings

Tags: sed, grep, string, text

I need to get inner text from this string `[%L10n.msg('foo')%]` so text between `[%L10n.msg('` and `')%]` so in this example I should get `foo`.

I found lot of examples but no one of them worked, I tried something like this:

```
echo "[%L10n.msg('foo')%]" | sed -n -e '/[%L10n.msg(\'/,/\')%]/p'
```

But I get error

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

**UPDATE:**
Imagine that my string can be inside this strig:

```
Some ' very [%% ]long ' text [%L10n.msg('foo')%] with lot of [%characters%]
```

**Tested file:**

```
Some ' very [%% ]long ' text [%L10n.msg('foo')%] with lot of [%characters%]
fefe
          <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/html/html_examples.asp'>HTML Examples</a>

          <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/html/html_exercises.asp'>HTML Exercises</a>

fefrheerghirlg wgwa g [%L10n.msg('foo')%]


<>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$ echo "[%L10n.msg('foo')%]" | sed "s/\[%L10n.msg('//; s/')%]//"
foo
```

or, with your NEW input sample,

```
echo "Some ' very [%% ]long ' text [%L10n.msg('foo')%] with lot of [%characters%]" | sed "s/^.*\[%L10n.msg('//; s/')%].*$//"
foo
```

or, with input altered for a second time (reads **Tested file** now), try

```
sed -n "/^.*\[%L10n.msg('/ {s///; s/')%].*$//;p}" file
foo
foo
```

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to do it with file? Like `sed "s/^.*\[%L10n.msg('//; s/')%].*$//" filename`?

Comment: Yes. Just try it.

Comment: It doesn't work, I updated question with my testing file, it just print whole file.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The two lines that contain the pattern just print `foo`.  The rest is something that comes out of the blue sky. See my edit...